# Здравствуй прошу помочь с планировщиком в OpenServer

Tags: php, laravel, openserver

Опишу суть: мне нужно чтобы запускался файл `C:\OSPanel\domains\testing\app\Console\Kernel.php` каждые 2 минуты,
начиная с 06:00 утра до 22:00 вечера. Я не знаю как это записать в
планировщике задач в Open Server. Прошу помочь если что-то не написал
скину
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Напиши просто каждые 2 минуты. А в скрипте напиши завершение работы, если время неподходящее.

Comment: А как это записать  командой

Comment: Эммм... что именно? что каждые 2 минуты? `*/2`.

Comment: Нет и именно активацию файла

Comment: Ну знаете... если написали скрипт, который не боитесь запускать на боевом сервере, то уж как-нить получить текущее время да сравнить с заданными границами сможете, я полагаю...

Comment: Я думаю что-то вроде такого (\*/2 * * * *) по примерам с https://pechenek.net/programming/php-programming/openserver-i-cron-zapuskaem-php-skript/